# Error sending simple Email through Python Script

Tags: python, email

I would first like to state that I am new to Python and coding in general. Slowly teaching myself in my spare time, so bare with my incompetence. This script is grabbing usernames actively connected to my SDE (SQL database), then adding them to a list. appening "@company.com" to the end to send them an email alerting them to save their data and log off before server maintenance.

This script was provided the software vendor here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/using-python-scripting-to-batch-reconcile-and-post-versions.htm

The error I receive is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jhead\Desktop\Scripts\ArcPy\SDE_Maintenance.py", line 32, in             <module>
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, MESSAGE)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\smtplib.py", line 723, in sendmail
self.rset()
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\smtplib.py", line 462, in rset
return self.docmd("rset")
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\smtplib.py", line 387, in docmd
return self.getreply()
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\smtplib.py", line 363, in getreply
raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Here is my code block containing the email section:

```html
import arcpy, time, smtplib

# Set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = 'Database Connections/admin.sdeLakeWorth.sde'
# Set a variable for the workspace
workspace = arcpy.env.workspace

# Get a list of connected users.
userList = arcpy.ListUsers("Database Connections/LakeWorth.sde")

# Get a list of user names of users currently connected and make email addresses
emailList = [user.Name + "@mycompnay.org" for user in arcpy.ListUsers("Database Connections/LakeWorth.sde")]

# Take the email list and use it to send an email to connected users.
SERVER = "EXCAS.Mycompany.org"
FROM = "SDE Admin <myname@mycompany.org>"
TO = emailList
SUBJECT = "SDE Maintenance is about to be performed"
MSG = "Auto generated Message.\n\rServer maintenance will be performed in 15 minutes. Please save all open GIS files and exit out."

# Prepare actual message
MESSAGE = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, MSG)

# Send the mail
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, MESSAGE)
server.quit()
```

As requested I added a few print statements before the scripts attempts to send the email, see below:

```html
print FROM
print TO
print SERVER
print SUBJECT
print MSG

# Send the mail
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, MESSAGE)
server.quit()
```

and the return:

```html
SDE Admin <myemail@mycompany.org>
[u'DBO@lakeworth.org', u'"MYLAKEWORTH\\GRHOADS"@lakeworth.org', u'DBO@lakeworth.org']
EXCAS.MyLakeWorth.org
SDE Maintenance is about to be performed
Auto generated Message.

Server maintenance will be performed in 15 minutes. Please save all open GIS files and exit out.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Scripts\ArcPy\SDE_Maintenance.py", line 39, in <module>
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, MESSAGE)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\smtplib.py", line 723, in sendmail
    self.rset()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\smtplib.py", line 462, in rset
    return self.docmd("rset")
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\smtplib.py", line 387, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\smtplib.py", line 363, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

So I edited my name/ email obv but it appears the email list is not grabbing the names only which will created a invalid email address to be sent to... hmmm I guess that's one issue but the error states I am being disconnected or the server cannot connect am I missing something in the smtp code which would fix this?

Comment: myname@mycompany..org

Comment: that was just a typo when I posted it in here, i removed my real email and company domain.

Comment: any other copy paste mistakes in the code? :)

Comment: Why don't you try printing TO, FROM and MESSAGE variables to see if they are correct. And BTW, usually variables are named in lower case and constants in upper case

Comment: The only copy edits I made were the senders email, and the company domains. I agree however this is the code format ESRI provided, the link is in the OP to see original source code

Comment: "Why don't you try printing TO, FROM and MESSAGE variables to see if they are correct"

Comment: updated the OP as requested

Comment: I wasn't asking to see your code with print statements, I was asking you to print out those values and **confirm for yourself that they are correct**

Comment: Oh, well it did tell me my sender list is wrong but that doesnt explain the error I am receiving.